# How can I create a memory storage to use as a context information for my OpenAI-ChatGPT Python Script?

Tags: python, openai-api, chatgpt-api

I wanted to make a smart assistant capable of storing all historical conversations that I have with it.

My idea is to be able to have long discussions that can be stored and retrieved over time as I expand some topics that I want to research.

I have a directory with the following files:
[image: Files containing historical and important information.]

This is the code I am using to recurrently place the memory at the beginning of the prompt, prior to entering it to the model:

```
import openai 
import os


from PIL import Image
import requests
import os



openAIKey='APIKEY'

prompt="\n Hi Duncan. You don't seem to be talking. Can you try saying something else?"

def talk(prompt,n=1,flex=0.5,flex_type='temp',memory=False,record_memory=False,memory_address=r'G:\My Drive\0- Personal\07- Duncan\memory',verbose=True):
        
        
    openai.api_key=openAIKey
    
    model_engine = "text-davinci-003"
    
    # Retrieve memory
    os.chdir(memory_address)
    
    memory_txt=''
    if memory:
        filelist = os.listdir()
        for filename in filelist:
            with open(filename) as f:
                file = open(filename, "r", encoding='utf-8')
                contents = file.read()
                memory_txt += contents
    '''           
    elif os.path.isfile(os.path.join(memory_address, 'memory.txt')):
        with open(os.path.join(memory_address, 'memory.txt')) as f:
            memory_txt = f.read()
    '''
    
    if memory:
        prompt = memory_txt + prompt

            
    if flex_type=='temp': 
        completion = openai.Completion.create(
            engine=model_engine,
            prompt=prompt,
            max_tokens=1012,
            n=n,
            stop=None,
            temperature=flex)
    elif flex_type=='top_n':
        print('top_n Pending...')
            
    response_array=[]
    for i in range(n):
        response = completion.choices[i].text
        response_array.append(response)
        
        if verbose==True:
            print()
            print(response, end='\n----------------------------------------------------------------')
        
        if record_memory:
            with open(os.path.join(memory_address, 'memory.txt'), 'a') as f:
                f.write(response + '\n')
        
    
    
    return response_array

if __name__=='__main__':
    
    
    memory=True
    record_memory=True
    flex_type='temp'
    n=1
    flex=0.5
    verbose=True
    memory_address=r'G:\My Drive\0- Personal\07- Duncan\memory'
    prompt='Welcome Duncan. I am so happy to meet you. \nHi Duncan! I am testing your talking function. What memories can you read?'
    
    ra=talk(prompt=prompt,n=n,flex=flex,flex_type=flex_type,memory=memory,memory_address=memory_address,verbose=verbose)
```

However it does not seem to be very responsive, and after some interactions it stops giving any answers.

Any idea how this could be improve?

Comment: You should renew your APIKEY, now it has been shared, anybody can use it

Answer (score 0):

I believe `openai.ChatCompletion.create` is what you are seeking for: [ChatCompletion introduction](https://platform.openai.com/docs/guides/chat/introduction)

Comment: That thing is that ChatCompletion is focused on Conversation. I actually want to have other type of information on that memory. I am considering trying Llama Index.

Comment: Then you can use the system role to teach things to the assistant without having to include them in the conversation, but remember you have a token limit